# is there any way to solve" project=Project.objects.get(pk=pk) "

Tags: python, django, django-urls

why is it that when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/1/ an error occur it says DoesNotExist and 
when I try http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/2/ it works without any error.i think the problem is either in urls.py or views.py

my url code :

`

```
urlpatterns =[
url(r'^$', views.firstindex, name='firstindex'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/',views.project_detail, name='project_detail'),]
```

and this is the view.py

```
`def project_detail(request,pk):
project=Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
context={
    'project':project
}
return render(request,'project/detail.html')
```

.

Comment: It means there is no `Project` with `id=1`, that's it.

Comment: If you're using sqlite as your database I'd suggest getting https://sqlitebrowser.org so you can inspect your data and verify whether the project exists or not.

Answer (score 3):

> i think the problem is either in `urls.py` or `views.py`

There is no logical error. A `Model.objects.get(..)` will raise an error (1) it can not find any record for the given filter; or (2) it can find *multiple* records for the given error. `DoesNotExist` thus means it did not find a `Project` with that primary key. If you look into the database, you will likely find out there is no `Project` with `id=1`.

You can use the [**`get_object_or_404(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) to return a HTTP 404 in the case it can not find such project, like:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def project_detail(request, pk):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    context = {
        'project': project
    }
    return render(request, 'project/detail.html', context)
```

Note that you forgot to pass your `context` to the `render` call.

Comment: Simple and straightforward answer. I like it.

Comment: yeah, thank you very much, it's working now. I like it.